# how to send file from server to client using indy

Tags: delphi, indy

I look for an example, how to receive a file from server (I use Indy)
I want to send to server some demand

On client:

```
MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('SEND_FILE');
MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('1.XLS');
```

On Server

```
procedure TServerMainForm.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext); 
var AStream : TMemoryStream;
    filesize : Integer;
    line, filename: String;
begin

    line := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
        if line = 'SEND_FILE' then
        begin
            filename := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();

            AStream := TIdFileStream.Create(filename, fmOpenRead + fmShareDenyNone);
           try
               AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write('FILE_DOWNLOAD'); //send command "FILE"
               AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(ExtractFilename(filename)); // send file name
               AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(IntToStr(AStream.Size)); //send file size

               AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(AStream);
           finally
               FreeAndNil(AStream);

           end;
```

and then on Client

```
if MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(10);
    if MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
  end;
  S := MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn();

  if S = 'FILE_DOWNLOAD' then
  begin
        MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.LargeStream := True; 

        if MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
        begin
          MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(10);
          if MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
        end;

         Filename :=  MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn(); //filename
            S := MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn(); // filesize
            FileSize := StrToInt(S);
            AStream := TIDFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(Paramstr(0)) + '\XLS\' + Filename, fmCreate);
            try
                AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(AStream, Filesize, False);
            finally
                FreeAndNil(AStream);
            end;
```

But it doesn't works.
Any file is not created on client;
Can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

When sending the `FILE_DOWNLOAD` reply, the server is calling `IOHandler.Write(String)` instead of `IOHandler.WriteLn()` to send the `FILE_DOWNLOAD` and filename strings. The strings are not being terminated with `CRLF`, but the client is using `ReadLn()` to read those strings. So it never reaches the point where it tries to create the file and read into it.

That being said, I would suggest a slightly alternative design for your protocol and code.

You don't need to send filenames on their own lines. They should be on the same lines as the commands that they belong to.

`TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` and `TIdIOHandler.ReadString()` can handle sending/reading the stream size for you. You don't need to send/read the size manually, and certainly not as a  string.

Try this instead:

Client

```
var
  XLSFolder: string;

...

MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('SEND_FILE 1.XLS');

...

if MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
begin
  MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(10);
  if MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
end;
S := MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn();
Cmd := Fetch(S);
if Cmd = 'FILE_DOWNLOAD' then
begin
  AStream := TFileStream.Create(XLSFolder + S, fmCreate);
  try
    MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
    MyIdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadStream(AStream, -1, False);
  finally
    AStream.Free;
  end;
end;

...

initialization
  XLSFolder := ExtractFilePath(Paramstr(0)) + 'XLS\';
```

Server

```
procedure TServerMainForm.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  AStream : TFileStream;
  cmd, params, filename: String;
begin
  params := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
  cmd := Fetch(params);
  if cmd = 'SEND_FILE' then
  begin
    filename := ExtractFilename(params);
    try
      AStream := TFileStream.Create('<some path>\' + filename, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    except
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('FILE_DOWNLOAD_ERR ' + filename);
      Exit;
    end;
    try
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('FILE_DOWNLOAD ' + filename);
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(AStream, 0, True);
    finally
      AStream.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```