# Indy TCPClient Send File to TCPServer Leadng Spaces and a @ Character

Tags: delphi, indy

I have just started "playing" with Indy. Used this post [how to send file from server to client using indy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079812/how-to-send-file-from-server-to-client-using-indy) and altered it so that my Client is the one Sending Data to the Server.

**Client** has following code to send Data :

```
procedure TForm1.btnConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TCPClient.Host:='192.168.88.117';
  TCPClient.Port:=32832;

  TCPClient.Connect;

end;

procedure TForm1.btnSendClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  AStream : TFileStream;
begin
  if not TCPClient.Connected then Exit;

  TCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('SEND_FILE '+GetComputerName+FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd_hhnnsszzz',now)+'.txt');

  try
    AStream := TFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\1.txt', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);

    TCPClient.IOHandler.LargeStream := true;
    TCPClient.IOHandler.Write(AStream, 0, True);

  finally
    AStream.Free;
  end;

  TCPClient.Disconnect; // otherwise the file is locked on the server side

end;
```

**Server** has following code to receive Data :

```
procedure TForm1.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  AStream : TFileStream;
  cmd, params, filename : string;
begin
  params := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
  cmd := Fetch(params);

  if cmd = 'SEND_FILE' then
  begin
    filename := ExtractFileName(params);

    TThread.Queue(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Command '+cmd+' File Name '+filename);
      end
    );



    AStream := TFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\'+filename, fmCreate);
    try
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream:=true;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(AStream, -1, false);

    finally
      AStream.Free;
    end;

  end;
end;
```

It seems to function correctly , I have made two clients for my test and ran them from separate computers , the server was receiving data from both of them and was creating the data correctly.

I have only two Problems :

**1.** for some reason the File Received on the Server has always the same amount of leading spaces followed by a @ symbol.

Original File looks like this

```
HERE IS SOME STUFF
```

Received file on Server looks like this :

```
   @HERE IS SOME STUFF
```

**2.** It looks like that after every file Send I need to disconnect , otherwise Indy TCPServer keeps the file locked , is this expected behavior ? How can I tell if the File is done ? I will need to process the received files in another Thread one-by-one .

Thank you.

**UPDATE 1**

So as recommended by Remy I've altered the Server like this :

```
procedure TForm1.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  AStream : TFileStream;
  cmd, params, filename : string;
begin
  params := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
  cmd := Fetch(params);

  if cmd = 'SEND_FILE' then
  begin
    filename := ExtractFileName(params);

    AStream := TFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\'+filename, fmCreate);
    try
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('OK');

      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream:=true;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(AStream, -1, false);
    finally
      AStream.Free;
    end;
  end;

  params := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
  cmd := Fetch(params);

  if cmd = 'SENT' then
    RenameFile(filename,ChangeFileExt(filename,'.dat'));


end;
```

On the Client I moved the entire Transfer into a Thread using ITask like this :

```
procedure TForm1.BackgroundTransfer;
var
    TCPClient : TidTCPClient;
    AStream : TFileStream;
    Files : TStringDynArray;
    i : integer;
    isDone : boolean;
begin
  Files := TDirectory.GetFiles(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\1\','*.out');

  TThread.Queue(TThread.CurrentThread,
    procedure
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Length(Files)));
    end
  );

  if Length(Files) = 0 then Exit;

  TCPClient := TidTCPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    TransferActive:=true;
    TCPClient.Disconnect;
    TCPClient.Host:='192.168.88.117';
    TCPClient.Port:=32832;
    TCPClient.Connect;

    for i := Low(Files) to High(Files) do
    begin

      isDone:=false;

      if FileExists(Files[i]) = true then
      begin
        TCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('SEND_FILE '+Files[i]);

        try
          // wait for server
          repeat
            sleep(100);
            if TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn() = 'OK' then break;

          until ( true );

          AStream := TFileStream.Create(Files[i], fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);

          TCPClient.IOHandler.LargeStream := true;
          TCPClient.IOHandler.Write(AStream, 0, True);

          isDone:=true;
          TCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('SENT '+Files[i]);
        finally
          AStream.Free;
        end;

        if isDone = true then
          System.SysUtils.DeleteFile(Files[i]);
      end;

    end;
  finally
    TCPClient.Free;
    TransferActive:=false;
  end;

end;
```

I Check with a Timer every 10 seconds if the Task is running if not I create a new one like this :

```
procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
  if TransferActive = false then
  begin
    inc(ThreadTimer);
    Panel1.Caption:=ThreadTimer.ToString;
    Panel1.Color:=clRed;
  end
  else
  begin
    Panel1.Color:=clGreen;
  end;

  if ThreadTimer >= 10 then
  begin
    ThreadTimer:=0;

    TransferTask := TTask.Create(BackGroundTransfer);
    TransferTask.Start;
  end;
end;
```

If I understood it correctly Indy Keeps Track of the Connections in the Background . Connection A-A , B-B , C-C , they cannot get mixed up . I am asking this because from the Server and Client side I just send OK or SENT and it works . ( hopefully not just by pure luck )

This is important because once it is fully working , I will have multiple client (android devices) sending data to this server . And there will be quiet a high chance that sometimes more then one client will be uploading data.

I also tested this like what happens if I start copying files into the Clients INPUT Directory and the Copy is not Done but the Task start . It worked , on first run it detected 350 files on the next run 500 .

Also tested if I simply stop the Server what happens that works too . If I use the TCPServer.Active:=false;

On the Client side the WriteLn and ReadLn properly causes an Exception ( Server Timeout I guess ) if the connection is lost .

On the Server Side I simply rename the Received file from OUT to DAT once it is done . I am not 100% sure if that guarantees that the file was really 100% correctly transferred . I was however unable to produce a damaged file during my testings.

Anyway the Entire idea is :

TCPClient is running on a Android phone, where the User Scanns Barcodes , I create a control file from this which is then in 10 sec intervals uploaded to the server . And from then on Processed by the Server and sent to another server .

Regards

**UPDATE 2**

Removed this line from server :

```
 DelFilesFromDir(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName), '*.out', FALSE);
```

was a bad idea to put in inside the Execute method .

I will need to find another way to remove possible junk files .

Also TransferActive is a Global variable , and is being modified by the Transfer Background Thread. But since only one Thread is running at a Time, I thought it should be safe.

Comment: 1) There is nothing in this code that can cause extra bytes to appear in the received file. If those bytes do not exist in the source file, something else outside of Indy has to be interfering with the data. 2) No, you don't need to disconnect to finish the transfer. You are telling `Write()` to send the file size before the file data, and are telling `ReadStream()` to read that size before the data. That is preferable, and ensures the TCP connection can still be used after the transfer is finished. The received file is unlocked when the `TFileStream` is destroyed. Make sure that is happening.

Comment: Given the code shown, I don't see how what you describe can happen, for either #1 or #2, unless there is outside interference somewhere. The code itself is fine. Although, I would suggest making the client open the source file before sending the `SEND_FILE` command, and have the server send a success/fail reply back to the client after creating the target file before then letting the client send the file data.

Comment: On a side note, `ExtractFilePath()` includes a trailing backslash for you, and you really should not be using your application folder to write files to. Use `SHGetFolderPath()` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` to ask Windows for a folder within your user profile that you are guaranteed to have write access to.

Comment: Remy thank you for the help , it looks like both Problem 1 and 2 no longer exists . I have no idea what I did but after writing the first Android client and then going back to the old windows Project the problem was gone . It could be that maybe I did something wrong during my testing. Anyway now I have updated the code , it seems to work properly . But it would be great if you could comment it :)

Comment: ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) is only used for the Development Version . On Android I am working with the "Home" directory .